# How to run a bash command only if another command outputs something?

Tags: bash, git, shell

How can I run a command in `bash` or any other bash-like shell only if another command outputs something?

I am working on an API that updates the cache storage of a tool and commits the updated cache to GitHub. What I want to do is, after rebuilding the cache, I want to check if `git diff HEAD ./path/to/cache` outputs something and if it does, then I want to run `git add ./path/to/cache`.

Unfortunately, this doesn't work:

```
git diff HEAD ./path/to/cache && git add ./path/to/cache
```

I think because the first command doesn't return `false` or exit and instead outputs an empty string or nothing at all. So, what's the correct way to achieve this in `bash`?

Comment: Could you stub in `wc -l` and test for an output of `"0"`?

Comment: Does `git add ./path/to/cache` do anything if `./path/to/cache` hasn't changed yet?

Comment: @chepner `git add` doesn't output anything whether a file or directory has changed or not.

Comment: @tadman `git diff HEAD ./path/to/cache | wc -l` outputs `0` but since it doesn't exit the next command still runs.

Comment: chepner has a great answer.

Comment: @RafidMuhyminWafi My point is, if it doesn't do anything, you can skip running `git diff` at all.

Comment: @chepner But there are more steps to perform, ex: `git commit` and `git push`, and I want to silently exit without throwing any errors/warnings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer posted by @chepner is definitely the best for my use case. But my question was originally for any use case. If you want to achieve the same behavior for any other commands, you can use the `grep` command to check if the first command outputs anything.

```bash
git diff HEAD ./path/to/cache | grep -q . && git add ./path/to/cache
```

Comment: it might serve your current purpose but that doesn't check for an **empty** output. `somecmd | grep $` is a more correct way

Comment: This is the more accurate anser, but add `-q` flag to `grep` command!

Comment: @Fravadona you may invert command: `! git... | greq -q . && ...`

Answer (score 6):

Use the `--exit-code` option, which causes `git diff` to exit with 0 if there are no diffs and 1 otherwise. Then you can ignore the output.

```
git diff --exit-code HEAD ./path/to/cache || git add ./path/to/cache
```

Answer (score 0):

```bash
[ -z $(git diff HEAD ./path/to/cache) ] || git add ./path/to/cache
# [ EXPRESSION ], -z the length of STRING is zero.
# || If no, execute subsequent shell
```